# Status bar is hidden in IOS 7 ipad

Tags: ipad, ios7

Our iPhone application will display status bar in IOS 7 iPhone. but in non retina iPad with IOS 7.0.4, status bar is not visible. Non retina iPads open application in 2x mode and status bar is not visible. How can I solve this problem?

What I tried to figure out this problem is,

I just created a Master detail iPhone application, and run it on a non retina iPad with ios 7.0 version. It does not shows the status bar. But status bar is visible in iphone with ios 7.0 for the same application. Then I installed some applications like Foursquare that shows status bar in iPhone. However they also missing status bar in non retina ipad 2 and ipad mini.

Comment: There are tons of answers for this issue. In order to give you an appropriate answer for your problem you have to narrow down the possible issue by showing us some code or describe the navigation structure of your application

Comment: @Lukas I am sorry if I violated the rules of stack overflow. Actually I didn't change any thing to make this happen. I just created a Master detail iPhone application, and run it on a non retina iPad with ios 7.0 version. It does not shows the status bar. But status bar is visible in iphone with ios 7.0 for the same application. Then I installed some applications like Foursquare that shows status bar in iPhone. However they also missing status bar in non retina ipad 2 and ipad mini.

Comment: iPhone apps running 2x mode in iPad(_non-retina_) does not show statusbar. That's how it is and I couldn't find good enough reasons to post an answer. So... [reference 1](http://igeekshome.com/2013/07/10/ios-7-improves-2x-mode-for-non-retina-ipads/) + [reference 2](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/07/09/ios-7-beta-3-ipad-2x-apps-retina/)